# Related to visual force

Tags: visualforce

I am displaying two text fields in a page.

The texts are displaying using labels.

I want to hide one of the two texts for particular country, is this possible? Is this possible using jQuery or we can do that using VisualForce?

Comment: Can you please be more specific ?

Comment: Please post some part of code

Comment: You have to use rendered attribute of apex:label for e.g <apex:outputLabel rendered ="{!objLead.Country__c!='Country Name'}" value="{!objLead.Country__c}"/>

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using 'rendered' attribute for 'outputLabel'